# "missing right parenthesis" error with my VIEW statement (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I'm getting the following error with my SQL code :

> Error at Command Line:50 Column:1 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00907:
>   missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

This is my code

```
CREATE VIEW mytestview1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id BETWEEN 5 AND 200
  ORDER BY first_name asc

)
```

I want to create view based on this table : `Employees`

```
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove parentheses at all:

```
CREATE VIEW mytestview1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
AS 
  SELECT *
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id BETWEEN 5 AND 200
  ORDER BY first_name asc;
```

The problem is ORDER BY here. This will also work:

```
CREATE VIEW mytestview1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id BETWEEN 5 AND 200
  )
  ORDER BY first_name asc;
```

The create view definition is: `CREATE ... VIEW ... AS <subquery>`. Where `<subquery>` has the following syntax:

[image]

As you can see `ORDER BY` must be outside of the `(<subquery>)`